subset my .fam file using a .txt file of names
I have a .fam file in plink format, looks like this
 1        I001.HO 0 0 1 1
 2        I002.HO 0 0 1 1
 3   IREJ-T006.HO 0 0 1 1
 4   IREJ-T009.HO 0 0 1 1
 5   IREJ-T022.HO 0 0 1 1
 6   IREJ-T023.HO 0 0 1 1
 7   IREJ-T026.HO 0 0 1 1
 8   IREJ-T027.HO 0 0 1 1
 9   IREJ-T037.HO 0 0 1 1
10   IREJ-T040.HO 0 0 1 1
11   IREJ-T053.HO 0 0 1 1
12   IREJ-T064.HO 0 0 1 1
13   IREJ-T078.HO 0 0 1 1
14   IREJ-T090.HO 0 0 1 1
15   IREJ-T101.HO 0 0 1 1
16   IREJ-T103.HO 0 0 1 1
17   IREJ-T111.HO 0 0 1 1
18   IREJ-T184.HO 0 0 1 1
19   IREJ-T204.HO 0 0 1 1
20     MAL-005.HO 0 0 1 1
21     MAL-009.HO 0 0 1 1

but with thousands of lines.
But I only want a subset of these rows in my final data file.
I have a .txt file of each individual I want to keep.
So looks like
IREJ-T184.HO
IREJ-T204.HO
MAL-005.HO
MAL-009.HO

How can I use this .txt file to make a new file with only the rows that include those individuals listed in the .txt file? I want to keep all data in the row, not just the ID name.
Thanks!

Using any awk:
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next } $2 in a' file.txt file.fam
18   IREJ-T184.HO 0 0 1 1
19   IREJ-T204.HO 0 0 1 1
20     MAL-005.HO 0 0 1 1
21     MAL-009.HO 0 0 1 1

To learn about awk, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Thank you so much!! I am just starting out on my data science journey and this really helped me. I just ordered that book as you've made me realize how important awk is
